# Why are lines, output by this program, duplicated?

Tags: c, file-io

Ok, so, I am currently working on implementing a simpleshell history. Part of the requirement is to output all the commands to a file having them numbered per line.

I have everything else working well at the moment, but the output to the file is giving me a very specific issue. It is saving the commands and putting them in the file numbered, but it is giving me around 3 duplicate copies per command. Ex:

```
1 hello
1 hello
1 hello
2 there1 hello
2 there3 how1 hello
2 there3 how4 are1 hello
2 there3 how4 are5 you
```

I have searched over the previous topics on this site, and read up on file i/o. As far as I can tell, I am doing it correctly:

```
#include "parser.h"
#include "shell.h"
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

struct node {
   char info[MAXINPUTLINE]; //Struct setup for linked list.
   struct node *link;
} *start;

void create(char[]);     //Function prototypes.
void insert_end(char[]);
void last_cmd(char[]);    

int main(void) {
   char input[MAXINPUTLINE];
   int count = 2;
   start=NULL;
   char data[MAXINPUTLINE];
   FILE *file;
   file = fopen(".simpleshell_history", "w");
   char *history="history";
   char *last="!!";
   signal_c_init();

   printf("Welcome to the sample shell!  You may enter commands here, one\n");
   printf("per line.  When you're finished, press Ctrl+D on a line by\n");
   printf("itself.  I understand basic commands and arguments separated by\n");
   printf("spaces, redirection with < and >, up to two commands joined\n");
   printf("by a pipe, tilde expansion, and background commands with &.\n\n");

   printf("\nclsh$ ");

   fgets(data, sizeof(data), stdin);
   create(data);
   fprintf(file, "%d ", 1);
   fprintf(file, "%s", data);
   parse(data);

   printf("\nclsh$ ");

   while (fgets(input, sizeof(input), stdin)) {
      stripcrlf(input);
      parse(input);

      insert_end(input);
      fprintf(file, "%d ", count);
      fprintf(file, "%s", input);

      count++;
      printf("\nclsh$ ");
   }
   fclose(file);
   return 0;
}

//Functions below.

//Creation Function.
void create(char data[])
{
   struct node *temp;
   temp = (struct node *)malloc(sizeof(struct node));

   if (start == NULL)
   {
      strcpy(temp->info, data);
      temp->link=NULL;
      start=temp;
   }
}

//Insertion function
void insert_end(char data[])
{
   struct node *ptr, *tempnode;
   ptr = start;

   while(1)
   {
      if(ptr->link != NULL)
      {
         ptr=ptr->link;
      }
      else
         break;
   }
   tempnode=(struct node *)malloc(sizeof(struct node));
   strcpy(tempnode->info, data);
   tempnode->link=NULL;
   ptr->link=tempnode;
}

//Last command repeat function
void last_cmd(char input[])
{
   struct node *ptr;
   ptr = start;
   int i;
   int length=0;
   char temp[MAXINPUTLINE];

   while (ptr!=NULL)
   {
      ptr=ptr->link;
      length++;
   }

   ptr=start;

   for (i=0; i<length-1; i++)
   {
      ptr=ptr->link;
      strcpy(temp, ptr->info);
   }
   printf("%s", temp);
   parse(temp);
}
```

I understand that some of my previous questions have not been received well, but I have tried my hardest on this, and am only asking this question as a final resort. I hope that I have done it in a manner that isn't annoying or against any rules, and can work to improve my reputation around here.

Thank you.

Edit: Ok, so I've isolated the problem down to the file that parses the input. It is causing the duplication of the lines, but I can't figure out how at this point. Any help is appreciated, but I will keep at it either way, thanks again for all the tips and advice.

Parser:

```
#include "parser.h"
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <pwd.h>
#include <fcntl.h>
#include <limits.h>
#include <signal.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <sys/resource.h>
#include <sys/wait.h>

/* Static Variables Referenced only in this file */
static int pipefd[2];
static int background;
void parse(char *cmdline)
{
  char *cmdpart[2];

  pipefd[0] = PARSE_NOPIPE;    /* Init: default is no pipe */

  background = checkbackground(cmdline);

  /* Separate into individual commands if there is a pipe symbol. */

  if (strstr(cmdline, "|"))
   pipefd[0] = PARSE_USEPIPE;

  /* Must do the strtok() stuff before calling parse_cmd because
     strtok is used in parse_cmd or the functions parse_cmd calls. */

  cmdpart[0] = strtok(cmdline, "|");
  cmdpart[1] = strtok((char *)NULL, "|");
  parse_cmd(cmdpart[0]);
  if (cmdpart[1]) parse_cmd(cmdpart[1]);
}

/* parse_cmd will do what is necessary to separate out cmdpart and run
   the specified command. */

void parse_cmd(char *cmdpart)
{
  int setoutpipe = 0;        /* TRUE if need to set up output pipe
                   after forking */
  int pid;            /* Set to pid of child process */
  int fd;            /* fd to use for input redirection */

  char *args[MAXARGS + 5];
  char *filename;            /* Filename to use for I/O redirection */

  splitcmd(cmdpart, args);

  if (pipefd[0] == PARSE_USEPIPE) {
    pipe(pipefd);
    setoutpipe = 1;
  }

  pid = fork();
  if (!pid) {            /* child */
    if (setoutpipe) {
      dup2(pipefd[1], 1);    /* connect stdout to pipe if necessary */
    }
    if (!setoutpipe && (pipefd[0] > -1)) {
      /* Need to set up an input pipe. */
      dup2(pipefd[0], 0);
    }

    filename = parseredir('<', args);

    if (filename) {    /* Input redirection */
      fd = open(filename, O_RDONLY);
      if (!fd) {
       fprintf(stderr, "Couldn't redirect from %s", filename);
       exit(255);
      }
      dup2(fd, 0);
    }

    if ((filename = parseredir('>', args))) { /* Output redirection */
      fd = open(filename, O_WRONLY | O_CREAT | O_TRUNC, 0666);
      if (!fd) {
       fprintf(stderr, "Couldn't redirect to %s\n", filename);
       exit(255);
      }
      dup2(fd, 1);
    }

    if (!args[0]) {
      fprintf(stderr, "No program name specified.\n");      
      exit(255);
    }

    execvp(args[0], args);
    /* If failed, die. */
    exit(255);
  } else {            /* parent */
    if ((!background) &&
       (!setoutpipe))
      waitpid(pid, (int *)NULL, 0);
    else
      if (background)
       fprintf(stderr, "BG process started: %d\n", (int) pid);
    if (pipefd[0] > -1) {    /* Close the pipe if necessary. */
      if (setoutpipe)
        close(pipefd[1]);
      else                     
        close(pipefd[0]);
    }                           
  } /* if (!pid) */
  freeargs(args);
} /* parse_cmd()  */

/* splitcmd() will split a string into its component parts.

   Since splitcmd() uses strdup, freeargs() should be called on the
   args array after it is not used anymore. */

void splitcmd(char *cmdpart, char *args[])
{
  int counter = 0;
  char *tempstr;

  tempstr = strtok(cmdpart, " ");
  args[0] = (char *)NULL;
  while (tempstr && (counter < MAXARGS - 1)) {
    args[counter] = strdup(expandtilde(tempstr));
    args[counter + 1] = (char *)NULL;
    counter++;
    tempstr = strtok(NULL, " ");
  }
  if (tempstr) {         /* Broke out of loop because of num of args */
    fprintf(stderr, "WARNING: argument limit reached, command may be truncated.\n");
  }
}

/* expandtilde() will perform tilde expansion on str if necessary. */

char *expandtilde(char *str)
{
  static char retval[MAXINPUTLINE];
  char tempstr[MAXINPUTLINE];
  char *homedir;
  char *tempptr;
  int counter;


  if (str[0] != '~') return str;      /* No tilde -- no expansion. */
  strcpy(tempstr, (str + 1));          /* Make a temporary copy of the string */
  if ((tempstr[0] == '/') || (tempstr[0] == 0))
    tempptr = (char *)NULL;
  else {                  /* Only parse up to a slash */
    /* strtok() cannot be used here because it is being used in the function
       that calls expandtilde().  Therefore, use a simple substitute. */
    if (strstr(tempstr, "/"))
      *(strstr(tempstr, "/")) = 0;
    tempptr = tempstr;
  }

  if ((!tempptr) || !tempptr[0]) {    /* Get user's own homedir */
    homedir = gethomedir();
  } else {                  /* Get specified user's homedir */
    homedir = getuserhomedir(tempptr);
  }

  /* Now generate the output string in retval. */

  strcpy(retval, homedir);          /* Put the homedir in there */

  /* Now take care of adding in the rest of the parameter */

  counter = 1;
  while ((str[counter]) && (str[counter] != '/')) counter++;

  strcat(retval, (str + counter));

  return retval;
}

/* freeargs will free up the memory that was dynamically allocated for the
   array */

void freeargs(char *args[])
{
  int counter = 0;

  while (args[counter]) {
    free(args[counter]);
    counter++;
  }
}

/* Calculates number of arguments in args */

void calcargc(char *args[], int *argc)
{
  *argc = 0;
  while (args[*argc]) {
    (*argc)++;            /* Increment while non-null */
  }
  (*argc)--;            /* Decrement after finding a null */
}

/* parseredir will see if it can find a redirection operator oper
   in the array args[], and, if so, it will return the parameter (filename)
   to that operator. */

char *parseredir(char oper, char *args[])
{
  int counter;
  int argc;
  static char retval[MAXINPUTLINE];

  calcargc(args, &argc);

  for (counter = argc; counter >= 0; counter--) {
    fflush(stderr);
    if (args[counter][0] == oper) {
      if (args[counter][1]) {    /* Filename specified without a space */
       strcpy(retval, args[counter] + 1);
       argsdelete(args + counter);
       return retval;
      } else {            /* Space seperates oper from filename */
       if (!args[counter+1]) {    /* Missing filename */
         fprintf(stderr, "Error: operator %c without filename", oper);
         exit(255);
       }
       strcpy(retval, args[counter+1]);
       argsdelete(args + counter + 1);
       argsdelete(args + counter);
       return retval;    
      }
    }
  }
  return NULL;            /* No match */
}

/* Argsdelete will remove a string from the array */

void argsdelete(char *args[])
{
  int counter = 0;
  if (!args[counter]) return;    /* Empty argument list: do nothing */
  free(args[counter]);
  while (args[counter]) {
    args[counter] = args[counter + 1];
    counter++;
  }
}
```

Edit: Ok, so I got it. The parse(input) and stripcrlf(input) were messing with it. How, I'm not sure, but that's beside the point. What I needed to do in the end was to not just open up the file and leave it open until it was closed just before the end of the program. I had to do this: fopen(".simpleshell_history", "a"); fprintf(file, "%d ", count); fprintf(file, "%s\n", input); fclose(file); Basically, I had to open the file, put the stuff in, and then close it before the parser and such could have an effect. The output is perfect now. Thanks everyone for your help.

Comment: Starlincr32, Congratulations for submitting your question.  For next time, consider phrasing the title of your question, as a question.  Specifically, "Output file content duplication" is not actually a question; perhaps the title should be "Why are lines, output by this program, duplicated?"  (Feel free to edit this question to improve the title.)

Comment: You did not give a complete example. However, after commentting out all those do not exist functions/variables, I have managed to get a working program and it works as expected. So the cause of your problem is very likely in the code you did not show.

Comment: Fair enough, I had seen examples of people posting questions and just dumping massive amounts of code, so I tried to give a truncated example of what I thought was the problem.

I will edit it, and the title to make more sense, thanks for the feedback.

Comment: @StarIncr34 you should post a complete program so that other people can just compile it and see the problem when they run the program.

Comment: Ok, so I got it. The parse(input) and stripcrlf(input) were messing with it. How, I'm not sure, but that's beside the point. What I needed to do in the end was to not just open up the file and leave it open until it was closed just before the end of the program. I had to do this: fopen(".simpleshell_history", "a"); fprintf(file, "%d ", count); fprintf(file, "%s\n", input); fclose(file); Basically, I had to open the file, put the stuff in, and then close it before the parser and such could have an effect. The output is perfect now. Thanks everyone for your help.

Answer (score 1):

I removed irrelevant lines from the question code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

#define MAXINPUTLINE 100

int main(void) {
   char input[MAXINPUTLINE];
   int count = 2;
// start=NULL;
   char data[MAXINPUTLINE];
   FILE *file;
```

I modified the file name from ".simpleshell_history" to "simpleshell_history" so that the file was not hidden (for testing purposes).

```
   file = fopen("simpleshell_history", "w");  
// char *history="history";
// char *last="!!";
// signal_c_init();

   printf("Welcome to the sample shell!  You may enter commands here, one\n");
   printf("per line.  When you're finished, press Ctrl+D on a line by\n");
   printf("itself.  I understand basic commands and arguments separated by\n");
   printf("spaces, redirection with < and >, up to two commands joined\n");
   printf("by a pipe, tilde expansion, and background commands with &.\n\n");

   printf("\nclsh$ ");

   fgets(data, sizeof(data), stdin);
// create(data);
   fprintf(file, "%d ", 1);
   fprintf(file, "%s", data);
// parse(data);

   printf("\nclsh$ ");

   while (fgets(input, sizeof(input), stdin)) {
//    stripcrlf(input);
//    parse(input);

//    insert_end(input);
      fprintf(file, "%d ", count);
      fprintf(file, "%s", input);
```

I added the following two lines to allow a way to break out of the loop.

```
      if(0 == strncmp("quit", input, 4))
         break;

      count++;
      printf("\nclsh$ ");
   }

   fclose(file);
   return 0;
}
```

I ran the program:

```
> ./test
Welcome to the sample shell!  You may enter commands here, one
per line.  When you're finished, press Ctrl+D on a line by
itself.  I understand basic commands and arguments separated by
spaces, redirection with < and >, up to two commands joined
by a pipe, tilde expansion, and background commands with &.


clsh$ hello

clsh$ there

clsh$ QUIT

clsh$ QUIT

clsh$ quit
```

The content of the file "simpleshell_history":

```
1 hello
2 there
3 QUIT
4 QUIT
5 quit
```

The code seems to execute as expected with no unexpected "Output file content duplication".

Comment: Thank you for that. I had been focusing entirely on my file stuff, but it seems that the problem is in one of the other files (involving the stripcrlf(input) and parse(input) functions which are contained in other files.

You have helped to point me to the right path, so thank you very very much.

Comment: Ok, so I got it.

The parse(input) and stripcrlf(input) were messing with it. How, I'm not sure, but that's beside the point. What I needed to do in the end was to not just open up the file and leave it open until it was closed just before the end of the program. I had to do this:

      fopen(".simpleshell_history", "a");
      fprintf(file, "%d ", count);
      fprintf(file, "%s\n", input);
      fclose(file);

Basically, I had to open the file, put the stuff in, and then close it before the parser and such could have an effect.

The output is perfect now. Thanks everyone for your help.

Comment: add your remarks in your question, so they will be visible for people coming here (add Edit section to your question and post your comment there)